# I'm trying to use pysimplegui, but i cant re-run the window

Tags: python, pysimplegui

```
import sys
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import os

sg.theme('SandyBeach')

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Enter admin username and password')],
    [sg.Text('username', size =(7, 1)), sg.InputText()],
    [sg.Text('password', size =(7, 1)), sg.InputText()],
    [sg.Submit(), sg.Cancel()],
]

window = sg.Window('Admin loggin', layout, margins=(10, 10))

event, values = window.read()
window.close()

def loggin():
    global success
    success = False
    file = open('psw.txt','r')
    for i in file:
        a,b = i.split(",")
        b = b.strip()
        if (a == values[0] and b == values[1]):
            success = True
        else:
            print("wrong")
            
loggin()
if success == False:
    pass
    

print("next stage")
```

I'm trying to use pysimplegui, but I can't re-run the window. I'm trying to figure out how to call window(), so I can try logging in if you mess up. But whenever I try to run window(), it gives me an error that I can't open a window that's already been open. Any workarounds or ways to restart the scripts completely?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot re-use the layout by instance of element, call class of element required.
To recall a window, by using function call will be better.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def get_codes(filename):

    with open(filename, 'rt') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    codes = []
    for line in lines:
        a, b = line.split(',')
        codes.append((a.strip(), b.strip()))

    return codes

def login(codes):

    sg.theme('SandyBeach')

    layout = [
        [sg.Text('Enter admin username and password')],
        [sg.Text('username', size =(7, 1)), sg.InputText()],
        [sg.Text('password', size =(7, 1)), sg.InputText()],
        [sg.Submit(), sg.Cancel()],
    ]

    window = sg.Window('Admin loggin', layout, margins=(10, 10))

    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, 'Cancel'):
            print('Login Cancelled')
            success = None
        elif event == 'Submit':
            if (values[0], values[1]) in codes:
                success = True
                print("Login Successful")
            else:
                success = False
                print("Login Failed")
        break

    window.close()
    return success

password_file = 'psw.txt'
codes = get_codes(password_file)
success = login(codes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is different way. I added the os module so that you get a relative path, which will then work on any computer.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import os

def login():
    sg.theme('SandyBeach')
    layout = [
        [sg.Text('Enter admin username and password')],
        [sg.Text('username', size =(7, 1)), sg.InputText()],
        [sg.Text('password', size =(7, 1)), sg.InputText()],
        [sg.Submit(key='Submit'), sg.Cancel(key='Cancel')],
    ]
    window = sg.Window('Admin loggin', layout, margins=(10, 10))

    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == 'Cancel' or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break
        else:
            filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'psw.txt') # <-- Use this so that you have a relative path. 
                                                                           #        This way it works on any machine
            with open(filename, 'r') as file:
                file = open(filename, 'r')
                for i in file:
                    a,b = i.split(",")
                    b = b.strip()
                    if (a == values[0] and b == values[1]):
                        sg.popup_ok("Welcome to your account!")
                        window.close()
                        break
                    else:
                        sg.popup_error("Incorrect credentials. Try again.")
                        continue
    
login()
```